# Make individual cosmos views display same rating

Tags: swift, xcode

I have two separate cosmos views in my project: one in a collection view, and one in the detail view that is pushed whenever an item in the collection view is tapped.

Howe can I make it so these different cosmos views (and potentially other cosmos views) display the same star rating?

I have tried linking the two separate cosmos views to a single swift file in order to make a new class that displays the cosmos rating, however xcode doesn't seem to allow me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

for what I understand you already can show two cosmos views in your controller, you just need to figure out how to put the same rating to all of them, right?

If so, I think you can set the rating the the 2nd view in the delegate methods of cosmos

didFinishTouchingCosmos and or didTouchCosmos

there you just need to set mySecondCosmos.rating = Int(rating)

If you want to handle this with multiple cosmos then you probably want to tag them and then evaluate the tag in the delegates to apply your logic there, which probably will be a big if statement

Comment: Hm ok this makes sense. However I still don't understand which class i should store my cosmos rating view in? I currently have written all my cosmos code in the tableview cell detail viewcontroller class, but here I'm not able to access it in other places. When trying to make a new class and connect my cosmos view I'm not able to do that either as it's just giving me warnings :S

Comment: Do you have your code on some repository you can share? I think that way will be faster to understand what are you trying to accomplish